# create snapshot automatically in Google Cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, snapshot

Try to set up a snapshot schedule in Google VM console and attached the snapshot schedule to the disk. Everything looks good, but it just not running and no snapshot is created at the specified time.

Here is the instruction what I followed. 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots

Anyone has the same problem and know what wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question with the output from `gcloud beta compute resource-policies describe [SCHEDULE_NAME]`

Answer (score 0):

We are in the same situation.

I have tested different time schedules and frequency but no snapshots have been generated.

For the time being, we've resorted back to using Auto-snapshot tool:

> > https://github.com/jacksegal/google-compute-snapshot

Of which have been working without issues.

Comment: @MapperkidsLee I have contacted Google Cloud Support using our Role-Based support account and they have confirmed there is an issue and currently they are rolling out the fix. Here is the public issue tracker:

>> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124654199

Hope this helps :)